# many `a` in my sentence with purple

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, determiners

Suppose I have a set of numbers. Then, suppose further that I take a sample of this set. Which of my sentences is correct? and why?

*Let (0,2) be a sample from a set S of discrete numbers*

or

*Let (0,2) be a sample from set S of discrete numbers*

Comment: If you're trying to use formal mathematical language, then **subset** might be a better choice than **sample**.  Also, curly braces {} are customary for (sub)sets rather than parentheses (), which are more commonly used for vectors or coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. When you are first introducing an unknown object in a discussion (in this case, some arbitrary set S of discrete numbers) you have to precede the noun with the indefinite article 'a' or 'an'. Using the indefinite article is not optional in English, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could say that is:

> Let (0,2) be a sample from a set of discrete numbers, S.

or

> Given a set of discrete numbers, S, let (0,2) be a sample from S.